# Can I cross the border from Ioannina Greece to Albania

Tags: customs-and-immigration, albania, greek-citizens, eu-id-card

Can I cross the border from Ioannina Greece to Albania with my Greek ID card or do I need a passport?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to enter Albania with only a Greek ID, however you need to be sure that it is the new Greek ID which is with Latin letter.

Still a few older ones ID's are existing with only greek letters. With these you won't be allowed to enter in case of a border control.

Comment: What do you mean with 'in case of a border control'?

Answer (score 1):

EU citizens have been allowed into Albania with their national IDs since summer 2006

As stated by the [Albanian MFA](http://www.punetejashtme.gov.al/files/userfiles/Regjimi_i_vizave_per_te_huajt_26.01.2017.pdf) (page 1):

> GRQIA: PASAPORTË & LETËRNJOFTIM

meaning:

> GREECE: PASSPORT OR ID CARD

However, in countries outside the EU/EFTA, such as Albania, only the new, bilingual card is a valid travel document.